# How to build dynamic grid in app

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having trouble with where to start on this problem. I have a Rails app and I want to build a dynamic grid within it. What I mean by this is that I want to be able to input a row of data (i.e., from one of my tables) within one cell of the grid. Then I want to be able to move the cell around to a different location of the grid. Ultimately having many of these cells that are freely able to be moved on a grid. Any assistance would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: "What I mean by this is that I want to be able to input a row of data (i.e., from one of my tables) within one cell of the grid" -> 1) Did you instead mean like "What I mean by this is that I want to be able to input a row of data (i.e., from one of my tables) within one row of the grid"? Or did you really mean you want all of these data inside one cell? 2) Are you using tables or a framework (i.e Foundation or Bootstrap) when you meant by grid?

Answer (score 0):

You should check out jQueryUI draggable https://jqueryui.com/draggable/